# Kivi - How to change text of label based on variable taken from mysql

Tags: python, mysql, kivy, kivymd

I need to change a label based on the value of a row in MySql db. I have this table:

```
 |id_match |        match        |
 | 1       |   Juventus - Milan  |
 | 2       |   Roma - inter      |
```

I have this .py

```
import mysql.connector
from kivmob import KivMob, TestIds,  RewardedListenerInterface
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Builder.load_file("prove.kv")

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    db="db",
    host="127.0.0.1",
    user="root",
    password="-----")
c = db.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE if not exists partite(
id_match INTEGER,
match VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (id_match))
""")

class prono1(Screen):
    home = ObjectProperty(None)
    away = ObjectProperty(None)

    def get_match(self, id_partita):
        query = "SELECT partita FROM db.partite where id_partita = VALUES (%s)"
        values = (id_partita)
        c.execute(query, values)
        partita = c.fetchone() ## <---- In this variable I have the label that I want to display
        return print(partita)

class prono2(Screen):
    home = ObjectProperty(None)
    away = ObjectProperty(None)

    def addresultToDB(self):
        query = """INSERT INTO risultati (user_id, id_partita, home, away) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) 
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                    home = VALUES (home),
                    away = VALUES (away)"""
        values = (user_id, 2, self.home.text, self.away.text)
        c.execute(query, values)
        db.commit()
        print(c.rowcount, "record inserted.")

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    ID_global = StringProperty('cccc')


class MyApp(MDApp):
    user_id = StringProperty()

    def set_screen(self, screen_name):
        self.root.current = screen_name

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(prono1(name='prono1'))
        sm.add_widget(prono2(name='prono2'))
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

and this .KV

```
<Prono1>:
    name:'prono1'
    home: home
    away: away
    MDCard:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 300,200
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        elevation: 10
        padding: 25
        spacing: 25
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDLabel:
            size_hint_y: None
            size_hint_x: 1
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            text_size: self.width, None
            font_size: 20
            padding: 10, 20
            color: 0,0,0,1
            text: 'bla bla bla' #### <------------ name of the match that I want to display (WITH ID = 1 - so Juventus - Milan)
            halign: 'center'
        GridLayout:
            cols:3
            MDTextFieldRect:
                id: home
                halign:"center"
                font_size:30
            MDLabel:
                id: None
                text:" - "
                font_size:18
                halign:"center"
            MDTextFieldRect:
                id: away
                font_size:30
                halign:"center"
    MDRoundFlatButton:
        text: "Invia"
        font_size: 12
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.75,"center_y": 0.20 }
        on_press: root.addresultToDB()


<Prono2>:
    name:'prono2'
    home: home
    away: away
    MDCard:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 300,200
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        elevation: 10
        padding: 25
        spacing: 25
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDLabel:
            size_hint_y: None
            size_hint_x: 1
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            text_size: self.width, None
            font_size: 20
            padding: 10, 20
            color: 0,0,0,1
            text: 'bla bla bla' #### <------------ name of the match that I want to display (WITH ID = 2 - so Roma - inter)
            halign: 'center'
        GridLayout:
            cols:3
            MDTextFieldRect:
                id: home
                halign:"center"
                font_size:30
            MDLabel:
                id: None
                text:" - "
                font_size:18
                halign:"center"
            MDTextFieldRect:
                id: away
                font_size:30
                halign:"center"
    MDRoundFlatButton:
        text: "Invia"
        font_size: 12
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.75,"center_y": 0.20 }
        on_press: root.addresultToDB()
```

With the `def get_match()` I am fetching the value that I am looking for. But I don't know how to show in the label that I highlighted in the comment.
In this way, if I change the match for every id_match, I have the updated match in the label that I show.

Comment: Is "partita" a string?

Comment: Yes it is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
def build(self):
        self.sm = sm = ScreenManager()
        self.wid1 = wid1 = prono1(name='prono1')
        self.wid2 = wid2 = prono2(name='prono2')
        sm.add_widget(wid1)
        sm.add_widget(wid2)
        sm.ids['wid1']= wid1
        sm.ids['wid2']= wid2
        return sm
```

This way you'll be able to acces `prono1` and `prono2` instances from anywhere in your `.py` file.

Now, in the `.kv` file, set an `id` in the label you want to acces. For example:

```
        MDLabel:
            id: labl1   ## <------ Here you set the id
            size_hint_y: None
            size_hint_x: 1
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            text_size: self.width, None
            font_size: 20
            padding: 10, 20
            color: 0,0,0,1
            text: 'bla bla bla' #### <------------ name of the match that I want to display (WITH ID = 2 - so Roma - inter)
            halign: 'center'
```

To acces that label from `.py` file you have do:

```
App.get_running_app().sm.ids['wid1'].ids.labll
```

In the code above, `ids['wid1']` is your prono1 instnace, and `.ids.lbll` refrences the label with the `id:labl1`

Now you're able to edit that label from anywhere in your program, for example if you want to edit that label in the function `get_match` then:

```
def get_match(self, id_partita):
        query = "SELECT partita FROM db.partite where id_partita = VALUES (%s)"
        values = (id_partita)
        c.execute(query, values)
        partita = c.fetchone() ## <---- In this variable I have the label that I want to display
        App.get_running_app().sm.ids['wid1'].ids.labll.text = 'Text has changed'
        return print(partita)
```